# Doublesided mesh with 2 colors on front and back

Tags: three.js, webgl

We can have a `doubelSided` mesh in three.js with both side showing same color, but is it possible to have a doublesided mesh with different colors based on the normal direction?

My main requirement is to visualize the back face with a low-saturated color, so that its clear on which side the mesh is facing.

My current approach is to use two create 2 mehses - one with backsided, but this creates more triangles which I don't want

```js
const mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 'red' } );
const obj1 = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat1 );

const mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 'green', side: THREE.BackSide } );
const obj2 = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat2 );
```

---

- found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24896716/6908282), but the answer accepted is not my requirement
- also found [this in observable](https://observablehq.com/d/cb1cd7e75908891b) which I think should work, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to implement it as I'm new to shaders

Answer (score -1):

You could use an array of Materials. The array would contain 6 materials (or 2... but not 7+... ) for the cube map (faces). You could reference the same material multiple times, for example if it's a color.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/why-people-passes-array-of-materials-to-mesh/41272

You may also use a [stencil](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=sten#webgl_clipping_stencil), [CSG](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=csg#webgl_geometry_csg), or [some other](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-render-caps-like-webgl-clipping-stencil/36727) surface modifier. It may be easier or harder depending on your use case (complexity or animation).

For example, if inside is black, and your renderers alpha is black, and you set alphatest to false... and your shape is a torus knot... And you use alphaHash...

Basically you need to show a working example.

Comment: This is for a mesh with multiple faces, my question is to have 2 materials for a single face - front and back

Comment: if that's the priority, the Oculus left renderTexture is red, and then change the material in EffectComposer before your battery runs out.

Comment: I don't think I understood your comment above

Comment: Originally, you said "low-saturated color" for the back. Which is why I suggested some other things. I suggest the material FrontSide map is red, and the material color itself is green. Are you occluding a raycast radius, or... what is confusing?

Comment: The "low-saturated color" was just an example. But I Didn't understand how `oculus` or `EffectComposer` and would be helpful. And no i'm not occluding raycast radius.

Comment: Sorry, is Jul 27 at 10:18 local time, or GMT?

Comment: [All times on Stack Overflow are in UTC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322821/6908282)

Comment: No, I'm running a custom build.